# DSE SearchAnalytics with Scala error

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

By refering to [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/analytics/dseSearchAnalyticsOverview.html) link , I tried to query cassandra table in spark Dataframe

```
val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("CassandraSpark")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
          .master("local[2]")
          .getOrCreate();
```

The node which I'm using is SearchAnalytics node
With using this spark session , i tried sql query

```
val ss = spark.sql("select * from killr_video.videos where solr_query = '{\"q\":\"video_id:1\"}'")
```

Search indexing is already enabled on that table.

After running the program , here is the error i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `killr_video`.`videos`; line 1 pos 14;
```

'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `killr_video`.`videos`

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:691)
```

How can i get Cassandra data into Spark?

Comment: master should be dse cluster... `dse://localhost`

Comment: or you will have to create dataframe and use     `df.createOrReplaceTempView("")`

Comment: How do you submit your application - via `dse spark-submit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this error message it looks like that you're running your code using the standalone Spark, not via DSE Analytics (via `dse spark-submit`, or `dse spark`).

In this case you need to register tables - [DSE documentation describes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/byosGeneratingSparkSqlSchema.html) how to do it for all tables, using `dse client-tool` & `spark-sql`:

```
dse client-tool --use-server-config spark sql-schema --all > output.sql
spark-sql --jars byos-5.1.jar -f  output.sql
```

For my example, it looks like following:

```
USE test;
CREATE TABLE t122
       USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
       OPTIONS (
                keyspace "test",
                table "t122",
                pushdown "true");
```

Here is an example of `solr_query` that just works out of box if I run it in the spark-shell started with `dse spark`:

```
scala> val ss = spark.sql("select * from test.t122 where solr_query='{\"q\":\"t:t2\"}'").show
+---+----------+---+
| id|solr_query|  t|
+---+----------+---+
|  2|      null| t2|
+---+----------+---+
```

To make your life easier, it's better to use DSE Analytics, not the [bring your own spark](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/byosIntro.html).